# Showing a form from an another thread, not showing form in debug mode.

Tags: c#, winforms

My main process does not have a UI, what I am trying to do is loop through items and depending on the item show a form.

Here's what I have:

```
private void SomeMethod(UIObject uiObject, string id)
{
    var thread = new Thread(() => LoadForm(id, uiObject.ControlType));
    thread.Start();
} // breakpoint here
```

Notice that I haven't yet coded in any way to prevent the loop from running away, for now I'm setting a break point and trying to get it working in debug first.

Here is LoadForm:

```
private void LoadForm(string id, string controlType)
{
    var form = new AddControlForm();
    form.Show();
    form.ControlId = id;
    form.ControlType = controlType;
    Application.Run();
}
```

As you can see it all looks fairly standard, now the outcome I am looking for is the thread starts in SomeMethod, and since I set a break point, the main thread should be halted, since the form is created and shown in another thread, I expect it to be on screen and responsive.

That doesn't happen, the form is nowhere to be found. What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you break on a breakpoint, normally all threads are paused, so your `Application.Run()` is likely not called at all.

Maybe it works if you put a wait-loop in the `SomeMethod()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Application.Run(form)` in order to start a new message loop on the current thread.